# Data arrived late angular in different component

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I use angular 6 and firebase as backend.
I retrieve the data from the user and store in the localstorage, the login page redirects to the profile of the user. Nothing is displayed in the fields because the data arrives late. The deal comes after the page loads. I can not make promises by what the call to the data is made during the connection and not on the profile page.

SigninComponent.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    const email = this.siginForm.get('email').value;
    const password = this.siginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService.signInUser(email, password).then(
      () => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
             var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).on('value', 
                 (data) =>
                localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data.val()))

            );
          }
        });      
        this.router.navigate(['Acceuille']);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What is wrong with the code you shared? Or is the problem that the `userInfo` is not displayed in your view? If that is the problem, please share the view that is trying to display the data.

Comment: wait for the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {}) to return the user and then navigate to next page.

Comment: looks like `this.router.navigate(['Acceuille']);` should be up one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put this line "this.router.navigate(['Acceuille']);" inside the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() method after checking user in "if" block;

```
this.authService.signInUser(email, password).then(
  () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
         var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).on('value', 
             (data) =>
            localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data.val()));
            this.router.navigate(['Acceuille']); // navigation should be here
        );
      }
    });      
          },
  (error) => {
    this.errorMessage = error;
  }
);
```

Because onAuthStateChange waits for the observer waits until getRedirectResult resolves. [See how to get the currently signed in user in this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)